Communication Loss Between Parent and Child Windows After Allowing Pop-ups in Chrome on iOS
I'm encountering a specific issue with pop-ups in Chrome on iOS. When I attempt to open a pop-up using the following function:
private _createPopup(url: string): Window {
  const left = (window.innerWidth - POPUP_WIDTH) / 2 + window.screenX;
  const top = (window.innerHeight - POPUP_HEIGHT) / 2 + window.screenY;
  const popup = window.open(
    url,
    'Smart Wallet',
    `width=${POPUP_WIDTH}, height=${POPUP_HEIGHT}, left=${left}, top=${top}`
  );
  if (!popup) {
    throw new Error('Pop-up window failed to open');
  }
  return popup;
}

Chrome initially blocks it. After manually allowing the pop-up, it opens, but the connection to the parent window is lost, preventing any communication between them. To restore this connection, I have to close the pop-up and reopen it, which is not an ideal solution.
This problem appears to be specific to Chrome on iOS, as it doesn't occur on other browsers or platforms.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? Are there any solutions or workarounds to maintain communication between the parent window and the pop-up after manually allowing it in Chrome on iOS?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
I attempted to open a new window using the window.open() method, but encountered the same issue: the child window's window.opener is null, preventing communication with the parent window. I expected the child window to have access to the parent via window.opener to facilitate message exchange between them.
